# yii2 kartik-v/yii2-widget-fileinput installation

Tags: file-upload, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-extension

I installed yii2 fileupload extension with:

1. **php version 7 and linux (putty)**
2. **php version 7 and 5 and window (cmd)**

but failed!

**message that shown to me on composer is :**

./composer.json has been updated

Loading composer repositories with package information

Updating dependencies (including require-dev)

Package operations: 2 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals

– Installing kartik-v/bootstrap-fileinput (v4.4.8): Loading from cache

– Installing kartik-v/yii2-widget-fileinput (dev-master c549564): Cloning c549564

Failed to download kartik-v/yii2-widget-fileinput from source: Failed to clone https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-widget-fileinput.git, git was not found, check that it is installed and in your PATH env.

sh: git: command not found

Now trying to download from dist

– Installing kartik-v/yii2-widget-fileinput (dev-master c549564): Loading from cache

Package mongosoft/yii2-upload-behavior is abandoned, you should avoid using it.
 Use mohorev/yii2-upload-behavior instead.

Writing lock file

Generating autoload files.

and when i used this command :

```
echo '<label class="control-label">Add Attachments</label>';

echo FileInput::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'attribute' => 'attachment_1',
    'options' => ['multiple' => true]
]);
```

this error happend :

**Class ‘kartik\widgets\FileInput’ not found**

and message that shown to me on cmd was too long!!

Have resources been changed?
What can I do?

Is there a way to do it manually?

you can see this extension at : 
[yii2 fileupload extension](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-widget-fileinput)

Comment: But what failed?

Comment: @Yupik my question has been edited.tank you.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the first error shows that you must install `git` (for example in ubuntu you can do it with `$ sudo apt install git`).
The second error is because of a blur on the namespace of `FileInput` documentation. Based on [This line of code](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-widget-fileinput/blob/f34ed0f94e7371b3905d7d2d3eccaf55a8790b0e/src/FileInput.php#L10), you should use `kartik\file\FileInput` as the used namespace.